# Azure Notification Hub with .Net back-end - How to get trigger Azure Database Dependency

Tags: c#, cordova, azure-sql-database, azure-notificationhub

I'm having a problem with Notification Hub and GCM ... I want to Make SQL Dependency where whatever the value is changed in DB it will trigger Notification Hub and then GCM and received by my Mobile App Client.

What I've tried so far ...
Make A Logical App. Create a trigger but trigger not fired. I end up with an error like:

```
"message": "Microsoft SQL: The target table 'dbo.mytable' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause."
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use SQL Dependency Class on Azure SQL Database. For more information about it, please read [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/622493/service-broker-at-least-sqldependency-support-in-sql-azure) Connect item.

Comment: So I can Use Custom Connectors to trigger Notification Hub when Values has been Changed Right ??

Comment: All I am saying is that SQL Dependency is not supported on Azure SQL Database and that is the reason you are receiving errors when trying to use it with Azure SQL Database.